# Javascript running in facebox window

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebox

I'm modifying a website to have a pop up box appear when a user rates something prompting the user to login. Unfortunately the login process is something that I don't control and it uses a whole heap of javascript and redirects to do it and it seems that the javascript is failing.

Can javascript run in the modal box or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try isolating the JavaScript by putting it in an inline frame [iFrame] on a separate html document

Just a thought.  Haven't tested it.

Comment: Not sure if the way you suggested is the way I did it but I got it to work. Loaded a HTML doc that basically just had an iframe that linked to the login, styles are buggered but I'll get there